# Inserting values from a text file into Sybase SQL server?

Tags: sql-server, sybase

I have a text file (i.e. practice.txt) like the following:

```
COW29,104,F
DUCK49,20,D
BAT2,8,F
FISH52,3,F
```

except it has thousands of lines.

I would like to write an script that will insert all the rows into a Sybase SQL table like:

```
 name | number | class
 ---------------------
COW29  | 104    | F
DUCK49 | 20     | D
BAT2   | 8      | F
FISH52 | 3      | F
```

Thanks!

Comment: Provide an example of your code how you try to do it

Comment: Check out BCP, that should be useful for importing data

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16688884/how-to-specify-row-delimiter-when-using-bcp-with-a-format-file/16712845#16712845

Answer (score 0):

Try below command

bcp db_name..table_name in file_name -S server -U user -Ppswd -t',' -c