# Migration from Postgres to Sybase with a PHP Script

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, database-migration, sap-ase

I want to migrate about 10 tables from Postgres to Sybase with a PHP Script.

So far I finished the delete-script, which just empties all of the desired tables on the destination Database.

The migrate-script as of now, is able to connect to both databases and print out the content. Besides that, I am counting the rows for checking if the destination table matches the source table, following the later INSERT (I recently learned of parameter @@ERROR which check for successfull SQL properly and will adjust that).

---

My problem right now is that I get an ERROR message:

> Warning: sybase_query(): Sybase: Server message: 
>   Incorrect syntax near '1'. (severity 15, procedure N/A) in .../.../...

when trying to INSERT the selected rows from the Postgres database into the Sybase database.
Therefore I used the fetch_assoc method to read the data for each row. The problem of this method, it will return a string instead of an integer, as seen here: http://php.net/manual/de/function.pg-fetch-assoc.php

The specific point in my code lookslike this:

```
                while ($row = pg_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $insert_dst = $destDB->query("SET IDENTITY_INSERT " . $dst_sy_tbl . " ON INSERT INTO " . $dst_sy_tbl . " (Integerfield, SOME_TEXT1, SOME_TEXT2) VALUES(". $row['integerfield'] . " '" . $row['some_text1'] . "', '" . $row['sometext2'] . "')"  );
                }
```

The source tables integer is formatted as int4, the destination table integer is numeric(8,0). The mentioned method now tries to insert a string into the column "integerfield" which expects an integer formatted in numeric(8,0).

**Is there a better method in PHP to receive the data from Postgres, so that they are stored "as is", without first being formatted to a string and the need convert the string back to integer afterwards?**

---

Note: I also tried to get the wished result with plain SQL as seen on the board here: [Insert into ... values ( SELECT ... FROM ... )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25969/insert-into-values-select-from)

But on executing this on my databasetool it lacked the permission to access the SRC_Table because it is located on a different database. - Maybe within the php-script this will work, as both connections are already estabalished and I was able to print the content of both tables.

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT DST_Table ON INSERT INTO db_name.of.DST_Table(Integer, SOME_TEXT1, SOME_TEXT2) SELECT integer, some_text1, some_text2 FROM db_name.of.SRC_Table;
```

Comment: I totally misunderstood the ERROR message and thought it is bad if every line of the resultset is given as a string. In the end I am putting an SQL-insert command, which is made of strings anyhow. My mistakes were, that I handed the integers as '1' instead of just 1 . Another mistake was a false comparing method, I copied blind from the GO direction Sybase to Postgres Script, for the RETURN direction Postgres to Sybase I had to adjust "string" to "varchar" and "datetime" to "timestamp"

Answer (score 0):

If you can use import/export tools...

You should look at using the [BCP](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc30191.1573/html/utilityguide/X14951.htm) tool for importing data into Sybase.

This [similar SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16688884/how-to-specify-row-delimiter-when-using-bcp-with-a-format-file) will give you some help on the syntax to use. If you [export from Postgres into CSV format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120109/export-postgres-table-to-csv-file-with-headings) for example, you will be able to BCP that data into Sybase ASE